# Which could be the best approach to break a large xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, large-files

I'm working on a desktop project using WPF, framework 3.5.

This application has lots of screens, but all of them are presented using a single user control (basically a stack panel wrapped in a class with some extra logic), what I do is like push and pop screens depending on the user choices.

Now, all the screens (which are basically stack panels) remain in a single xaml file, and this file is becoming incredibly large and it's becoming really difficult to maintain and update.

So I was thinking that maybe I can create user controls for each screen on the application and that would break the xaml file, making it easier to work with, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach or the recommended approach, that's why I'll like to know what do other people do to handle this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not use resource dictionaries to break up the Xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource StackPanel1}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource StackPanel2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and the dictionaries would have content similar to this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel x:Key="StackPanel1">
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </StackPanel>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, now let me ask, if I use a resource dictionary wouldn't that mean that all the stack panels would be defined on the dictionary (like in your example) and thus the dictionary would be too big too, cause each stack panel is like 100 lines of code average, and I have like 10 - 15 stack panels, so wouldn't that be like breaking the large xaml to make a dictionary with the same problem?

Comment: put each panel in its own dictionary, and use dictionary merging as demonstrated in my code :) FYI, if you use Expression Blend then dont worry how big the XAML gets, in my opinion its not worth hand-cranking xaml most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a lot of sense to modularize your XAML into smaller files.  User controls are a very good way to do this - it's the first think I try when I need to do this, and I haven't needed to find a second.

The only real problem you'll run into is if the pieces of XAML you're trying to modularize are involved with each others' implementation details - like if you're binding controls in one to elements in another.  That raises the difficulty a bit, but only a bit.